# Removing a subview with a subview from a UIView without memory leaks

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, uikit

I made a custom `UITextView` for vertical Mongolian writing. It is made by subclassing `UIView`, which has a subview called `rotatedView`. This `rotatedView` itself has a `UITextView` subview. So there are three views: a parent, a child, and a grandchild.

[image]

The `UITextView` contains the actual text. The `rotatedView` is a container that gives the text the correct vertical orientation and line wrapping. The parent `UIView` is the container that allows autolayout to work normally in the Interface Builder. For more background, please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30907710/rotating-a-view-in-layoutsubviews) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30620291/how-to-make-a-vertical-uitextview-by-subclassing-it-from-uiscrollview-in-swift).

Whenever the parent `UIView` frame changes, the old `rotatedView` is removed and a new instance is made. Then the `UITextView` (a property of the custom `UIView` subclass) is added to the `rotatedView`.

What I am worried about is memory leaks. Since the grandchild view `UITextView` is a property of my custom view but `rotatedView` isn't. When I drop `rotatedView` on a frame size change, is any reference kept to it since the `UITextView` property is a subview of `rotatedView`?

This demo project can be found on [github](https://github.com/suragch/iOS-Mongol-App-Components/blob/master/Mongol%20App%20Componants/UIMongolTextView.swift), but here is the custom class code:

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable class UIMongolTextView: UIView {

    // ********* Unique to TextView *********
    private let view = UITextView()
    
    let mongolFontName = "ChimeeWhiteMirrored"
    
    @IBInspectable var text: String {
        get {
            if let txt = view.text {
                return txt
            } else {
                return ""
            }
        }
        set {
            view.text = newValue
        }
    }
    
    func setup() {
        view.text = self.text
        view.backgroundColor = self.backgroundColor
        view.font = UIFont(name: mongolFontName, size: 24)
    }
    
    
    
    
    // *******************************************
    // ****** General code for Mongol views ******
    // *******************************************
    
    private var oldWidth: CGFloat = 0
    private var oldHeight: CGFloat = 0
    
    // This method gets called if you create the view in the Interface Builder
    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
    
    // This method gets called if you create the view in code
    override init(frame: CGRect){
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.setup()
    }
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.setup()
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        
        // layoutSubviews gets called multiple times, only need it once
        if self.frame.height == oldHeight && self.frame.width == oldWidth {
            return
        } else {
            oldWidth = self.frame.width
            oldHeight = self.frame.height
        }
        
        // Remove the old rotation view
        if self.subviews.count > 0 {
            self.subviews[0].removeFromSuperview()
        }
        
        // setup rotationView container
        let rotationView = UIView()
        rotationView.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: CGSize(width: self.bounds.height, height: self.bounds.width))
        self.addSubview(rotationView)
        
        // transform rotationView (so that it covers the same frame as self)
        rotationView.transform = translateRotateFlip()
        
        
        
        // add view
        view.frame = rotationView.bounds
        rotationView.addSubview(view)
        
    }
    
    func translateRotateFlip() -> CGAffineTransform {
        
        var transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
        
        // translate to new center
        transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, (self.bounds.width / 2)-(self.bounds.height / 2), (self.bounds.height / 2)-(self.bounds.width / 2))
        // rotate counterclockwise around center
        transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, CGFloat(-M_PI_2))
        // flip vertically
        transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, CGFloat(-1), CGFloat(1))
        
        return transform
    }

}
```

I am using the same general method for text views, labels, and table views.

## Update

The advice below is extremely useful. The things I've already tried to apply can be seen in the code of [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/100546/set-a-font-for-a-uitextview-if-the-font-is-nil-or-not-equal-to-desired-font).

However, no one has yet commented on my original reason for posting this question. That is, is there any sort of memory leak issue with removing and then recreating a subview that itself has a property subview? I'm going to take that to mean that there isn't a big problem with this, so I won't worry about it.

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> @IBInspectable var text: String {
>     get {
>         if let txt = view.text {
>             return txt
>         } else {
>             return ""
>         }
>     }
>     set {
>         view.text = newValue
>     }
> }
> ```

Just a small thing to comment on, however, a couple of notes here.

First, with Xcode 7, which is right around the corner, `UITextView`'s `text` property will be a regular `String` instead of `String!`, so we can eliminate this `if` statement altogether.

However, in the meantime, this becomes a lot cleaner with the nil-coalescing operator:

```
get {
    return view.text ?? ""
}
```

---

Another minor comment:

> ```
> transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, CGFloat(-1), CGFloat(1))
> ```

Using the `CGFloat` constructor here is unnecessary.  We can just use the literals:

```
transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, -1, 1)
```

Comment: As an interesting side note, I also applied this to my custom Label. However, I had to use `return view.text ?? ""` rather than `return view.text` even though I am using Xcode 7 beta. It works for TextView but not for Label. Maybe this is just an issue with the beta version.

Comment: The nil-coalescing operator will only work with optional types.  It's unnecessary with non-optionals because they can't be `nil`.  And to be clear, the nil-coalescing operator has always existing in Swift.  What's changing between versions is the return types of some of the UIKit properties.

Comment: I thought it was interesting that `label.text` is an optional while `textView.text` isn't. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31909863/swift-why-is-label-text-an-optional-but-textview-text-is-an-unwrapped-string)

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> func setup() {
>     view.text = self.text
>     view.backgroundColor = self.backgroundColor
>     view.font = UIFont(name: mongolFontName, size: 24)
> }
> ```

So, we've got this code in here, but it looks like the method is only called from the initializers and from `awakeFromNib`.  So what happens if the background color is programmatically set after this point?

But there's another problem... we're stuck using a specific font and a specific size.  There's no way to set the font to anything else.

Also, setting the `view.text` here doesn't even make sense.  Remember how the `text` property we created works?  It just returns `view.text ?? ""`.  So in effect, this line is just a shortcut for:

```
view.text = view.text ?? ""
```

And ultimately, setting the `view`'s background seems wholly unnecessary here.  Why don't we just give all of the view's a *transparent* background and let `self.backgroundColor` show through?

Finally, methods should be verbs.  They describe an action.  But `setup` is actually a noun (properties should be nouns).  We can fix this by capitalizing the `u`, making the method name `setUp`--a verb.

So, `setUp` should do our one-time, first time initialization.  What do we need to do here?

- Set all of our subviews to have a clear background color.

That's all we really need to do at this point.

The `text` property we created takes care of the text field's text.

We should similarly create a font property.  Or perhaps other fonts don't work this text view.  We can still make a `fontSize` property to allow the user to set the size they want.  Nicely, `fontSize` could be an `IBInspectable` too (`UIFont` unfortunately cannot).

So, either we want an entire font property exposed to allow the user to pick font:

```
var font: UIFont = UIFont(name: mongolFontName, size: 24) {
    get {
        return view.font
    }
    set {
        view.font = newValue
    }
}
```

If we make all of the subviews have clear backgrounds, we don't have to worry about doing anything to handle this.  We can just rely on the default behavior of setting a view's background color, which we're inheriting from `UIView` already.

---

You also need to keep in mind that we're missing out on *a lot* of the functionality of the default `UITextField` with your class because you haven't provided a way to access all of the functionality.

There are at least two massive things I can think of off the top of my head:

- placeholder
- delegation

We can't set any placeholder text for your textfield.

We can't delegate the textfield at all.