# Set a font for a UITextView if the font is nil or not equal to desired font

Tags: ios, swift, null, user-interface, uikit

## Main question

I am setting a font for a UITextView that is a subview in a custom view. I only set it if the user didn't specify the font size in the Interface Builder.

I have the following working code

```
if self.view.font == nil || self.view.font!.fontName != mongolFontName {
    
        view.font = UIFont(name: mongolFontName, size: defaultFontSize)
    
}
```

but the `if` line seems more verbose than it needs to be. Is there a more concise way of getting the same result?

## Extra background info

This is a continuation in the same vane of [a previous question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/100431/removing-a-subview-with-a-subview-from-a-uiview-without-memory-leaks). After making changes based on advice from the answers there (though still more to do), the code I have now is

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable class UIMongolTextView: UIView {

    // ********* Unique to TextView *********
    private let view = UITextView()
    let mongolFontName = "ChimeeWhiteMirrored"
    let defaultFontSize: CGFloat = 17
    
    @IBInspectable var text: String {
        get {
            return view.text
        }
        set {
            view.text = newValue
        }
    }
    
    @IBInspectable var fontSize: CGFloat {
        get {
            if let font = view.font {
                return font.pointSize
            } else {
                return 0.0
            }
        }
        set {
            view.font = UIFont(name: mongolFontName, size: newValue)
        }
    }
    
    func setup() {

        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        
        // set font if user didn't specify size in IB
        if self.view.font == nil || self.view.font!.fontName != mongolFontName {
            
            view.font = UIFont(name: mongolFontName, size: defaultFontSize)
        }
        
    }
    
    
    
    
    // *******************************************
    // ****** General code for Mongol views ******
    // *******************************************
    
    private var oldWidth: CGFloat = 0
    private var oldHeight: CGFloat = 0
    
    // This method gets called if you create the view in the Interface Builder
    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
    
    // This method gets called if you create the view in code
    override init(frame: CGRect){
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.setup()
    }
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.setup()
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        
        // layoutSubviews gets called multiple times, only need it once
        if self.frame.height == oldHeight && self.frame.width == oldWidth {
            return
        } else {
            oldWidth = self.frame.width
            oldHeight = self.frame.height
        }
        
        // Remove the old rotation view
        if self.subviews.count > 0 {
            self.subviews[0].removeFromSuperview()
        }
        
        // setup rotationView container
        let rotationView = UIView()
        rotationView.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: CGSize(width: self.bounds.height, height: self.bounds.width))
        self.addSubview(rotationView)
        
        // transform rotationView (so that it covers the same frame as self)
        rotationView.transform = translateRotateFlip()
        
        // add view
        view.frame = rotationView.bounds
        rotationView.addSubview(view)
        
    }
    
    func translateRotateFlip() -> CGAffineTransform {
        
        var transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
        
        // translate to new center
        transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, (self.bounds.width / 2)-(self.bounds.height / 2), (self.bounds.height / 2)-(self.bounds.width / 2))
        // rotate counterclockwise around center
        transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, CGFloat(-M_PI_2))
        // flip vertically
        transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, -1, 1)
        
        return transform
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a much easier way of doing this.

```
if self.view.font?.fontName != mongolFontName {
    view.font = UIFont(name: mongolFontName, size: defaultFontSize)
}
```

We should always prefer optional binding and optional unwrapping (`?`) to forced (`!`).

When the value we're optionally unwrapping is `nil`, we just get `nil` back.  And of course, `nil` and `mongolFontName` aren't going to be the same (unless you've set up `mongolFontName` as `nil`), so we enter the `if`'s body.

Consider this example from the playground:

[image]